# Assign Class to variable with a String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm trying to do some of the project Euler problems in swift. 
I originally tried using the Playground, but found that to be incredibly slow, so I've instead made a simple single view app that will run them for me in the simulator. See below for my example:

[image]

The way I did this was I made a customer class called `ProblemClass` and then I make a new class for each problem that inherits from that class. After that, all I have to do is override the functions in `ProblemClass` and then the View Controller just loads all the information from the `Problem1` Class that inherited from `ProblemClass`.

When it segue's to the view that loads from `Problem1` (or any other problem), it gets the details by me setting the `currentProblem` variable during the segue. see below

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destination = segue.destination as! ProblemVC
    let cell = sender as! ProblemsTVCell
    let label = cell.label!

    switch label.text! {
    case "Problem 1":
        destination.currentProblem = Problem1()
    case "Problem 2":
        destination.currentProblem = Problem2()
    case "Problem 3":
        destination.currentProblem = Problem3()
    case "Problem 4":
        destination.currentProblem = Problem4()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is there a way to assign the Problem#() with a string, so I don't have to make hundreds of these cases? I have no idea what it would look like, and trying to google kept returning answers about #selectors. I don't know what it really would look like, but in my mind I'm thinking something like this.

```
destination.currentProblem = Class(name: "Problem4")
```

Let me know if what I'm asking isn't clear and I'll try to explain better.
Thank you in advance!

---EDIT---
Adding in my solution from the selected answer below.

So I changed the prepare function to this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destination = segue.destination as! ProblemVC
    let cell = sender as! ProblemsTVCell
    let label = cell.label!

    let problemName = label.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    let problemClass = NSClassFromString("Project_Euler.\(problemName)")! as! ProblemClass.Type
    destination.currentProblem = problemClass.init()
}
```

And to get the `init()` in my `ProblemClass` I made my class look like this:

```
class ProblemClass {

required init() {
    return
}

func title() -> String {
    return "Title"
}

func problem() -> String {
    return "Problem #"
}

func question() -> [String] {

    return ["No Question Yet"]
}

func answer() -> [String] {

    return ["No Answer Code Entered Yet"]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
let problemNumber: Int = 1
var className = "AppName.Problem\(problemNumber)"
let problemClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! Problem.Type
destination.currentProblem = problemClass
```

Comment: I think I'm almost there with what you gave me. Problem is my `ProblemClass` doesn't inherit from anything so it doesn't have an init(), and I have no idea how to make one when I'm not inheriting. But I need to basically add a step in there that is like this `destination.currentProblem = problemClass.init()` Or at least that is what I'm getting from the first link you sent.

Comment: @JasonBrady the solution should be added to the answer (not question)